# pandas loc does not adds value to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

So I want to add a value in an existing value for a specific location in pandas dataframe. And I tried it as follows:

```
import calendar
for index,row in data.iterrows():
    print(index)
    if row.mask:
        date = calendar.monthrange(int(row.year), int(row.month))
        date = pd.to_datetime(str(int(row.year))+'-'+str(int(row.month))+'-'+str(date[1]))
        diff = data.real - data.fiction
        df.loc[df.date==date, 'zeta']+=diff
```

But in the end after this operation value is same as previous and I dont get why as I am using loc which points to a specific positio AND can change values. But mine does not work.

Data Sample:

So there are two dataframes involved here. One is df which looks like:

```
{'date': [datetime.date(2018, 7, 1),
  datetime.date(2018, 7, 2),
  datetime.date(2018, 7, 3),
  datetime.date(2018, 7, 4),
  datetime.date(2018, 7, 5),
  datetime.date(2018, 7, 6),
  datetime.date(2018, 7, 7),
  datetime.date(2018, 7, 8),
  datetime.date(2018, 7, 9),
  datetime.date(2018, 7, 10)],
 'alpha': [899.8399999999998,
  804.2400000000001,
  824.6400000000001,
  903.7599999999999,
  761.2900000000001,
  766.7999999999998,
  765.0699999999998,
  882.8600000000001,
  741.8199999999999,
  729.6600000000001],
 'beta': [660.24,
  514.87,
  456.6600000000001,
  490.29,
  469.83,
  506.4,
  571.65,
  651.18,
  545.5,
  544.99],
 'gamma': [1555.5299999999988,
  1512.829999999999,
  1507.4699999999991,
  1491.1799999999994,
  1019.4199999999994,
  650.0699999999995,
  674.7599999999999,
  676.0899999999992,
  464.05999999999966,
  455.03000000000003],
 'delta': [178.02,
  150.75,
  136.14999999999998,
  147.51999999999998,
  160.93000000000004,
  131.96999999999997,
  117.31,
  131.88,
  160.57000000000008,
  158.73999999999998],
 'epsilon': [0.0,
  375.7099915,
  464.85501100000005,
  464.8450012,
  484.63500980000003,
  514.664978,
  471.16000369999995,
  459.8599853999999,
  461.4349976,
  441.9400024],
 'zeta': [282.9800053,
  156.5300011,
  109.93999609999999,
  83.86999995,
  168.62735590000003,
  170.31219380000002,
  73.63714508,
  119.776293,
  179.14328830000002,
  446.6358328],
 'total': [3576.6100052999986,
  3514.929992599999,
  3499.7150070999996,
  3581.4650011499994,
  3064.7323656999997,
  2740.2171717999995,
  2673.5871487799996,
  2921.646278399999,
  2552.5282859,
  2776.9958352000003]}
```

And data which looks like:

```
{'month': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
 'year': [2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020],
'fiction': [4904.049999999999,
  5098.29,
  8582.139999999998,
  13712.130000000001,
  20505.370000000003,
  3629.21,
  0.0,
  0.0],
 'real': [14528.33,
  12592.45,
  8582.14,
  13712.12,
  20505.4,
  19356.6,
  18205.0,
  13028.29],
 'mask': [True, True, False, False, False, True, True, True]}
```

The mask is being calculated as follows:

```
(data.real - data.fiction).map(int).map(bool)
```

Comment: what are you attempting with the line `if row.mask:` ?

Comment: Ohh its just a boolean value result of a calculation behind. It goes as follows if you must know: `(data.real - data.fiction).map(int).map(bool)`.

Comment: you provide very little detail about many objects in your code... please share a sample dataframe with `df.head(10).to_dict('list')` and your expected output from that sample, all as code blocks, so we can copy to an IDE and reproduce your results

Comment: @RichieV I have added the data sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two mistakes you had.

### Firstly NEVER go for column names after builtin functions.

mask is a builtin function and `if row.mask` will return True in any case. Because function will exist no matter you want it to exist or not  so practically no use of checking based on that. I added a print statement inside if statement. Just to make sure, try adding it in your if block and you will know the difference. (Incase you HAVE to name it that way, although I can't think of a situation where you have to choose a name of a builtin function, go like this: `if row['mask']` and don't test pandas' intelligence.)

### Secondly, .loc() DOES assign values. But they should match the destination dimensions.

You might be getting some error message for that. There is a good chance that you might want to have difference for that specific row (if not, it puts a big big  question mark on looping over whole dataframe) so you might want to use `row.real - row.fiction` instead of `data.real - data.fiction`. I made these two changes and dataframe changes as expected. Here is the code with changes you might want to plug in

```
import calendar
for index,row in data.iterrows():
    if row.maskr:
        print('Going for',index)
        date = calendar.monthrange(int(row.year), int(row.month))
        date = pd.to_datetime(str(int(row.year))+'-'+str(int(row.month))+'-'+str(date[1]))
        diff = row.real - row.fiction
        df.loc[df.date==date, 'zeta']+=diff
```